# Why some tests are failing when running detox in parallel?

Tags: automated-tests, ui-automation, e2e-testing, detox

I'm running Detox with Jest.
If i'm running the tests on 2 workers they all pass, but if i'm running the same tests on 4 workers some of the tests failing

Thanks for helping in advance.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I Managed to overcome this issue and minimize the amount a the failing tests running in parallel.
First I reduced the amount of workers to 3 instead of 4.
Second I configured the before and after hooks in every test file.

From this:

```
beforeEach(async () => {
    await device.launchApp({
        permissions: {
            notifications: 'YES',
            location: 'always',
            userTracking: 'YES',
            camera: 'YES',
            medialibrary: 'YES',
            photos: 'YES',
        },
    })
})
afterAll(async () => {
    await device.terminateApp()

})
```

To this:

```
beforeEach(async () => {
    await device.terminateApp()
    await device.launchApp({
        permissions: {
            notifications: 'YES',
            location: 'always',
            userTracking: 'YES',
            camera: 'YES',
            medialibrary: 'YES',
            photos: 'YES',
        },
    })
})
afterAll(async () => {
    await detox.cleanup()
    await device.terminateApp()
})
```

So before every test run detox making sure the app is terminated.
in addition I add detox.cleanup() after the tests are done for a better test closure

Hope this will be helpful for anyone who encounter this issue as me.